# String through 1 hole 3-torus

Tags: general-topology

**Okay So I had stayed up way too late thinking about this problem and I typed my question wrong.  The question is: How do I deform a 3 dimensional 1 hole torus to go around a line?** https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb0yn.jpg

---

---

*How do I deform a torus to go through the hole of a 3-torus?  I have searched and searched but I cant wrap my brain around it (hehe, get it?).

I can understand a 2-hole and deforming a two hole torus with a line through it and getting both holes to go around the line, but not the how to deform it for the first line.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that makes me remember http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Inside-out_torus_%28animated%2C_small%29.gif

Comment: 3-torus or 3-hole torus?

Comment: 1 hole 3 dimensional torus... and also I do not believe we are allowed to have it be a punctured torus

Comment: If I understand you, a 3-dimensional 1-hole torus is usually called a *solid torus*. However, I don't know what you mean by deforming it to go around a line. Are you thinking of it as embedded in 3D? Where is the line in relation to the solid torus initially?

Comment: Are you thinking about something like this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107782/continuously-deform-2-torus-with-a-line-through-one-hole-to-make-it-go-through-b

Comment: Almost but it doesnt start in a hole, and the torus has only one..I will draw a picture right now.

Comment: her is a link to the problem: [link](http://tinyurl.com/q7lpjae)

Comment: That link doesn't work for me. It says "forbidden."

Comment: my bad... I uploaded it to imgur. http://imgur.com/eabE5AX

Answer (score 1):

Okay, now that I know what the problem is, I can tell you it's impossible. There is no way to link the torus with the line by continuous deformation. The concept of linking number is relevant here. All the curves on the original torus have zero linking number with the line, but in the linked picture, the core curve of the torus has linking number $\pm 1$ with the line depending on how you orient things. (I'm assuming here the line goes to infinity, which is a case where we can define linking number.)

Comment: Can it be done by puncturing or any way at all?  My professor is insisting it is possible, but it could be that he is messing with us. And thanks for the help!

Comment: No, puncturing it doesn't help. The same argument applies.